# Visual Studio 2019 - set Docker context to solution root with multiple projects (to match docker-compose)

Tags: visual-studio, docker, .net-core, docker-compose, visual-studio-2019

I have some .Net Core projects which have reference to one project (library) in the solution.
I run them using docker-compose, and have the context set to solution root (src/) so that they all see the library.
It works well, but I can't run just a single project using VS built-in docker (as it has context set to project root, not solution).
How could I set the context settings for the project, while not breaking the docker-compose functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Your VS project file has an MSBuild property named `DockerfileContext`. Just crack open the project file in a text editor and you'll see it defined in a `<PropertyGroup>`. By default, it's set to "`.`", meaning the same directory as the project. You can set this to whatever you'd like. For example, to set it to the project's parent directory it would be set to "`..\`".

Comment: I didn't (and still dont) have this property in the project file, but somehow today when I tried to run the projects in docker they started working. Maybe when I run the docker-compose it somehow changed the configuration for all projects and required restart to apply?